# Optimising a MYSQL query that uses LIKE %search% on joined tables

Tags: mysql, select, optimization

I have a MySQL query that searches through a zipcode database for city names. The query takes about 4 seconds, to search through 620,000 zipcodes. I would like ideas how I can make this faster.

First, the tables:

I have a table of zipcodes. Each zipcode entry has 6 ints, that refer to words. I use joins from the words, to make zipcodes: "92121, San Diego, California, United States, CA, US"

If I know the exact zipcode, the query is quite fast:

[Full Question](https://blackvelvetcollection.com/question.txt)

I made this link to show the table and SELECT statement since StackOverflow appears to have some bugs when posting code.

However, if I do NOT know the zipcode and search by name, the query is really slow, as I must accommodate searching for all permutations of all words: "San Diego, CA", "San Diego, California", "San Diego, CA", "California San Diego", "92121 San Diego CA", etc

In order to accommodate all the permutations, I am doing a LIKE on every term, against every column. This is really slow (4 seconds) and I feel this statement can be made much more efficient.

The database contains all zipcode patterns, for all countries. Maybe I can search for "US", "CA", "UK", or "AU" beforehand, and limit the query to cities within the user"s home country?

Thoughts?

Comment: Do not post the link to the question text, insert it into your question. PS. `LIKE %search%` cannot be optimized, it always uses complete table scan.

Comment: The LIKE statement takes 0.001 seconds to complete. If I do SELECT city LIKE '%san%', then do SELECT city LIKE '%diego%' my total time is 0.00248 seconds. But when i do it as a single statement I am getting 3.x seconds.

Comment: @JohnMcCarthy - Is this what you tried? `WHERE city LIKE '%san%' AND city LIKE '%diego%'`  If will have to check the entire table, but is faster than some formulations.

Comment: Worse. I have to check (city LIKE %san% OR state LIKE %san% OR country LIKE %san%) AND (city LIKE %diego% OR state LIKE %diego%  OR country LIKE %diego%) which means each search term, multiplied by each column. San Diego California, US is 5 columns (city, state, country, state_shortcode, country_shortcode) times 4 terms.

Answer (score 1):

Taking the advice of Akina, where LIKE can't be optimized, I did a CONCAT of all the columns then did a single LIKE, rather than multiple LIKES against each column separately. I used a SELECT inside a SELECT to do this.

I then removed the GROUP BY, and added LIMIT 1, so that the database could bail on finding the first zipcode rather than scanning the entire database.

Finding a zipcode, on a 650k worldwide database, went from 3.5 seconds to 0.025 seconds.

Comment: But if you search for a zip code that occurs late in the database, it will have to scan _almost_ all the rows of the table. And if you search for a zip code that is not present in your database at all, it will have to scan the entire table, and then give you an empty result.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:  Put all 7 words into a string; index it with `FULLTEXT`, have `innodb_ft_min_token_size` set to 2.

Now you can do

```
MATCH(str) AGAINST('+diego' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
MATCH(str) AGAINST('+921*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

and lots of other things.  All will be much faster than 3.5s.

Read about Fulltext; there are some limitations.

Comment: Oh thank you for innodb_ft_min_token_size. I gave up on FULLTEXT because of the 3 character limit but I will experiment with this.